# If Statement across multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have been trying to get this working for the past 2 hours but I am stuck.

Background: I am doing an audit of our sites and want a Master sheet which shows the health of the audit.

Problem: I have 4 sheets, 1 called Master and the other 3 called London, Edinburgh and Dublin. Here is what I am trying to do.

If cell B3 in sheets London, Edinburgh and Dublin has the word yes, I want cell B3 in Master to turn Green. If the 3 sheets have even 1 No, then it should turn yellow and if 2 or more are No then B3 in Master should turn red.

So far I have this and it isn't working. I cant seem to figure out how to match data in more than 2 sheets, definitely no idea how to do what I described above. I believe I need arrays but my excel knowledge is limited.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(London!B3 & Edinburgh!B3, Master!$A:$A,0),"yes",),"no")
```

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks
Neha

Comment: Do you need cell B3 showing string `Red`, `Yellow`, or `Green`; or change it's interior color?

Comment: Change its interior colour please

Answer (score 0):

A formula option:

```
=LOOKUP((London!B3="YES")+(Edinburgh!B3="YES")+(Dublin!B3="YES"),{0,2,3},{"RED","YELLOW","GREEN"})
```

Comment: This works perfectly .. Thanks @Olly  .. You are a whiz! How can I get the formula to actually change the colour of the Master sheet B3 cell instead of just writing the word please? I am very very thankful

Comment: @NehaGarg you will need conditional formatting with three rules.  Formulas in them selves will not change the color of the cell.

Comment: And how do i do that. Sorry for asking to be spoon fed but I really dont know much about excel. No idea why I have been charged with this. lol

Comment: Actually Olly I worked it out. Thanks a lot for all the help

Answer (score -1):

This is too complicated to do in one cell. (Yes, you can use a flashy formula, but if you ever want to change it or add a new worksheet, you'll be stuck again.)

Assuming C3 is available on each sheet, put in that cell

```
=IF(LOWER(B3)="yes", 1, 0)
```

Then on your master sheet have a cell that is simply the sum of those cells.

Conditionally format that master sheet cell, and you're done.